# AngularJS and the effect of the promise value when calling a local function - undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I am really new to Angular and am working on bypassing a DB call that I don't want to use any more. Between the response from the code that calls the DB and my new code that accesses a stored variable (via getter), the only difference is that the response object's `$promise` value is `undefined` (in the new code) instead of `Object` (in the old code).  This difference seems to be resulting in the following error: `TypeError: undefined is not a function`; I am using AngularJS v1.2.0-rc.3  Do I have to be using an async call for the `$promise` value to be set to an `Object` or is there a way to manually set/cast it?

Here are some code snippets:

Factory (QueryService):

```
var recentResponse = null;

var getRecentResponse = function() {
   return recentResponse;
};

var doQuery = function (input, handler, errorHandler) {
    MyResource.saveInput(input, function (response) {
            // save JSON response locally (NEW!)
            recentResponse = response;
            // save JSON response to DB via handler (old)
            handler(response);
        },
        function (errors) {
            errorHandler(errors);
    });
};

var getQueryById = function(id, handler) {
    // query the DB
    MyResource.getObjectWithId(id, function(response) {
        handler(response);
    });
};

return {
    doQuery: doQuery,
    getQueryById: getQueryById,
    getRecentResponse: getRecentResponse
};
```

Controller:

```
function loadQueryById(id) {
   // call the DB query
   QueryService.getQueryById(id, function(response) {
      $scope.query = response;
      $scope.query.val2 = $scope.getVal2();
   });
}

function loadLastQueryResponse() {
   // load from local var
   $scope.query = QueryService.getRecentResponse();
   $scope.query.val2 = $scope.getVal2();
}

loadQueryById($routeParams.id);
loadLastQueryResponse();

$scope.getVal2 = function() {
    return $scope.query.value2 ? JSON.parse($scope.query.value2) : "";
};
```

When `loadQueryById()` is called `$scope.query` is set with the `$promise` field = `Object`; when `loadLastQueryResponse()` is called, all the `$scope.query` fields are exactly the same except `$promise` is `undefined`, and the following line fails with the error when trying to call `$scope.getVal2()`:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at loadLastQueryResponse (MyController.js:20)
```

The `$scope.query.$resolved` field is `true` in both cases.

Does my Angular version have something to do with it, or the fact that I am not waiting on a promise to be fulfilled (because I don't need to be)?  I also tried calling `QueryService.getRecentResponse()` with a handler, and I also tried using the `then()` format (which I may or may not have implemented correctly) but the result was the same.

Function and variable names have been changed to protect the innocent. Thanks in advance!

Comment: what if you move the statement $scope.getVal2 = function () {..} above
function loadLastQueryResponse(){..} ?

Comment: where is code for `getRecentQueryResponse`. can you share complete service code

Comment: What methods are actually returned from factory?

Comment: @entre, apologies, getRecentQueryResponse is actually getRecentResponse() - i mistyped it when converting the function names to generic ones.

Comment: @laurent, that appears to have worked!  I'm surprised that the code is not executed too early - but also that it works correctly with the old way and not with the new.  Do you think it is a timing issue?  Just that the old way will take more time (even though it's only a DB GET, it is slower than a local var.

Comment: @charlietfl All the methods are returned by the factory; I updated the original post to reflect that.  (But that was definitely a problem that tripped me up earlier in development!)

Comment: The main difference is that you db call is asynchronous whereas the other one is synchronous.

Comment: @laurent Do you want to post the answer or should I? (Just so I can mark it resolved.)

Comment: It is ok, you can do it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered by @laurent in the comments, the issue was that once the request was no longer calling the DB asynchronously, and instead calling the function synchronously; so the `$scope.getVal2 = function () {..}` declaration had to be moved above `function loadLastQueryResponse(){..}` so the calling code within the latter knows about the function implementation of the former.